# how to modify the length of one column in table and view concurrently?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqldatatypes

I have a table in oracle data base. I have changed the length of one column from `VARCHAR2(50)` to `VARCHAR2(100)`. The problem is that the length of the column does not change in views. any suggestions?

I am using `ORACLE SQL Developer  Version 4.0.2.15`.

Comment: How are you determining that the length is not changing?  I don't have that problem.

Comment: A view is just based on the base table, so when you will have a string beyond 50 characters, you will see that in the view too. VARCHAR2 is a variable length string data type, so increasing the size doesn't increase the length of the existing string. **It might be that you just need to right click on the `VIEWS` in the `connection` in SQL Developer and click `refresh`.**

Comment: Refresh you database.

Comment: already have refreshed my connection and  my views but nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the change of the table the view gets an INVALID state, you must either [recompile the view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4004.htm) or simple select from the view to get it valid again and have the right definition. While the view is invalid, it retains the old definition, which is what you see.

See below a little illustration

```
create table tab 
(col1 varchar2(50));

create or replace view vtab as select col1 from tab;

select table_name, data_length from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'COL1';

TABLE_NAME DATA_LENGTH
---------- -----------
TAB                 50 
VTAB                50 

alter table tab modify (col1 varchar2(100));

select table_name, data_length from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'COL1';

TABLE_NAME DATA_LENGTH
---------- -----------
TAB                100 
VTAB                50 

select status from user_objects where object_name = 'VTAB';

STATUS
-------
INVALID
```

The view is invalid, therefore the column length is wrong. Compile the view or simple issue `select * from VTAB`

```
alter view vtab compile;

select table_name, data_length from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'COL1';

TABLE_NAME DATA_LENGTH
---------- -----------
TAB                100 
VTAB               100
```